# postgresql multiple hosts in one URI?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to config multiple hosts in connection strings according to this article

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html

but I'm wondering the data sync problem.I have to configure postgresql replication , right ?

let's say I define 3 hosts in one URI , connect to node1 , insert 100 rows to DB , and shutdown or poweroff node1 , that 100 rows wont automatical sync to node2 , is that correct ?
if I want to do that , I have to configure postgresql streaming replication , is that correct ?

Comment: Does this question not have to be in : dba.stackexchange.com stack ?

Comment: Can you show an example of your connection string? Or are those multiple connection strings (for separate connections to separate databases)?

Comment: postgresql://host1,host2,host3/dbname?target_session_attrs=read-write 
exactly the same in that post

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Database servers won't sync automatically only because of a single client's connection string. You need to configure replication explicitly.

Documentation on replication: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-replication.html